# v-naigation-drawer hides on small screen with no hamburger menu or anything to get it back

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Using vuetify and have a layout like:

```
<v-app id="inspire">
    <v-system-bar app>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <Clock/>
    </v-system-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer" app
  >
  ...
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  ...
```

Using vue 2, with router and no vuex yet.

My problem is that when my browser window gets narrow the drawer hides but there is no hamburger icon to click to get it back.

How do I make it so that it toggles on smaller screens, instead of just disappearing altogether?

Comment: You may be able to use `mini-variant` prop if you don't want the menu to completely disappear. Otherwise you will need a button outside on the drawer that will toggle the v-model value.

Answer (score 2):

The navigation drawer is nothing more then the sidebar itself. You could add a prop `disable-resize-watcher` to disable this functionality.

When you want to trigger the state of the navigation drawer you can use `v-model` to open and close the navigation drawer for example add `v-model="menuIsOpen"` to your navigation drawer and add `@click="menuIsOpen = !menuIsOpen"` to a button to make that trigger the navigation drawer.

Comment: I don't want to disable and I can't pass a prop from the parent component and then use it in v-model b/c I get errors about modifying props...

Comment: Could you provide an example? (codepen, codesandbox or a github repo)